# Re-render parent component on property change triggered by child

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm **trying to build some re-usable components**, like a input text component for example. I want to customise it with all sorts of built-in methods, validations, associated labels and error labels, etc.

I've mostly managed to to it. **What I'm trying now to achieve** is to re-render the parent component (and all children implicitly) when a property is changed.

**I'm getting the callback** triggered in the parent and assigning the value to my **text** property, but the DOM does not update with the new value.

*Parent Component*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<input-text [text]="text" [onChange]="onChange"></input-text> <p>The text is now {{text}}</p>'
})

export class ParentComponent {
    text: string;

    onChange($text) {
        this.text = $text;
        console.log('onChange', this.text); // <-- it gets here on child input
    }
}
```

*Input Text - Child Component*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'input-text',
    template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [value]="text"/>',
})

export class InputTextComponent {
    @Input() text: string;
    @Input() onChange: Function;
}
```

So this is it. Writing in the child component triggers the parent's `onChange` function, I update the `text` property but the template message does not change.

I'm basically trying to create an uncontrolled component, simliar to React. Also, if I add more `input-text` children they don't share the same text, although the parent's `text` property is a single one and theoretically is passed to all children.

**What I've tried**

I've also tried using `ngOnChanges` in the child component [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180151/1300817) and to use the `changeDetection` property [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407516/1300817) but neither worked. The problem appears to be in the parent
I also tried using `@Input()` in the parent component instead for the text property.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple but can't figure out what.
When `text` changes I want to see that in the DOM, and if I use 10 `input-text` components that get passed the same `text` property I would expect all of them display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was simple like I expected. I was [looking over this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40840934/1300817) as a workaround and noticed that in the parent `onChange` function it didn't recognise `this.chRef` or other properties.

So I immediately realised I wasn't properly binding my function. So I changed the parent template to contain

```
[onChange]="onChange.bind(this)"
```

and it now works properly.

Nevertheless, if you have suggestions as to how this code could be improved please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an arrow function in your ParentComponent like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: '<input-text [text]="text" [onChange]="onChange"></input-text> <p>The text is now {{text}}</p>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    text: string;

    onChange = ($text) => {
        this.text = $text;
        console.log('onChange', this.text); // <-- it gets here on child input
    }
}
```